# How to I fetch the very latest DNS records from a recently updated domain?

Tags: networking, dns

I recently updated my domain and added CNAME and TXT records, and don't want to wait for the changes to propogate. How can I go directly to the source and query the DNS records to verify everything is correct?

I tried

```
dig @dns1.name-services.com mydomain.com any
```

because that is my name service (enom.com), but it still displayed the old info.

Here are my settings that will not propogate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajhmx.png

Answer (score 1):

Assuming dns1.name-services.com is where you made the change, you should see the update unless your DNS host puts the mods in a queue. Since you are not seeing the updates, contact the host and ask them what their turn around is from the time you make a change to when their script implements it.

if you own it all and you're running bind or something, remember to `service named restart` after you make your changes.

If you want to view all the subdomains of your root via dig do

```
dig axfr kizbit.com
```

Comment: Ok I asked them, but Enom is no good. They told me to ask my reseller. My resller just gave a vague response "if you are using our servers, the changes happen without any
delay whatsoever, as long as you click to save them." It's already been several days. Here are my settings that will not propogate: http://i.imgur.com/MvYJUTq.png

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I didn't know how `dig` works, and you have to query the actual sub-domain to get any information. I thought everything would appear as it did in the online form if you just look at the root domain!

```
$ dig @dns1.name-services.com _amazonses.kizbit.com any

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_amazonses.kizbit.com.  1799    IN      TXT     "C9DR1H5StZrI97xjWjkVcd/2jwW9R05MBr49T8IyooI="
_amazonses.kizbit.com.  1799    IN      SOA     dns1.name-services.com. info.name-services.com. 2002050701 10800 3600 604800 3600
```